# How to stop/kill consumer once it read the data?

Tags: java

I'm using publisher/subscriber model to deliver a message in a round robin fashion. Here I'm using 2 consumers to process the request. I want to stop one consumer once it  processes one request. How can I stop one consumer? If so the remaining request will go to other consumer. If consumer fails to send back then what happens to the (persistent)data? Will it be lost or will it be delivered to other consumer ?

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, Exception {
        BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI(
                "broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)"));
        broker.start();
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            // Producer
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                    "tcp://localhost:61616");
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue("customerQueue");

            // Consumer
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
                if(i == 0)
                {
                consumer.setMessageListener(new ConsumerMessageListener("Consumer " + i));
                }


                consumer.setMessageListener(new TestingOnc("Consumer" + i));


                }

            broker.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

The producer call that I'm using

```
public synchronized static void createMQRequestForPoster(Long zoneId, List<String> postJobs, int priority) throws JMSException {

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                    Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Destination dest = session
                    .createQueue(SMCConstants.ACTIVEMQ_POST_REQUEST);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(dest);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

            logger.info("List of jobs adding into poster queue: "+postJobs.size());
            for(String str : postJobs) {

                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                obj.put("priority", priority);
                obj.put("zoneId", zoneId);
                obj.put("postJobs", str);
                logger.debug(obj.toString());
                message.setText(obj.toString());
                message.setIntProperty(ActiveMQReqProcessor.REQ_TYPE, 0);
                producer.send(message);
            }
        } catch (JMSException | JSONException e) {
            logger.warn("Failed to add poster request to ActiveMq", e);
        } finally {
            if(connection != null)
                connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

am able to send and receive the message.